# Gettext not working, what's wrong?

Tags: php, gettext, poedit

I'm using gettext for adding different translations into my webpage. I've just installed it and I think it works fine. I also use Poedit for the *.po* files.

This is the code I have for my gettext testing:

```
<?php
// I18N support information here
$language = "en_US";
putenv("LANG=" . $language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);
//
// test if gettext extension is installed with php
//

if (!function_exists("gettext"))
{
    echo "gettext is not installed\n";
}
else
{
    echo "gettext is supported\n";
}
echo '<br>';
echo _("HELLO WORLD");
echo _("TEST TRANSLATION");
?>
```

That code, returns me 'gettext is supported', but instead of showing me the translations, it shows me 'HELLO WORLD' and 'TEST TRANSLATION'.

This is my messages.po file:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-03-22 14:45+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-03-22 15:23+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-Language: English\n"
"X-Poedit-Country: UNITED STATES\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: utf-8\n"

# Test token 1
msgid "HELLO WORLD"
msgstr "Hello World!"

# Test token 2
msgid "TEST TRANSLATION"
msgstr "Testing translation..."
```

And it's inside my 'Locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES' folder, with also a *messages.mo* file successfully converted. *(I've hidden the info of the file, the name, the project, etc.)*

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT: I also might add that I use Ubuntu with PHP, Apache and all this things installed.

Comment: @IliyaReyzis Nope, I'm using Ubuntu with PHP, Apache, Mysql.. Installed in it.

Comment: After I made sure that the generated locale file shares the same charset as my MO file and `bind_textdomain_codeset()`, the translations started working for me. Some locales can be represented by multiple charsets, and their default charset is *not* UTF-8 (e.g. zh_CN uses GB2312). I use `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to manage the charsets. You can read this article for more information: https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/09/troubleshooting-php-gettext/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been having headaches with this one too. I added this and it worked:

`putenv('LANGUAGE=en_US');`

Next to that I use the following:

```
$domain = 'woohoo';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8');
putenv('LANGUAGE=en_US');

if( ENV != 'live' ){
    // reset caching nocache is a simlink to "."
    bindtextdomain($domain, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../locale/nocache');
}

bindtextdomain($domain, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);
```

Also, in my setup it only started working when I added the iso code to the .po file:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language: en_US\n"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I've put the code that you gave me and it seems to work!!! Thanks :D

Comment: I can't believe it was just that! I lost hour searching and it was just a matter of a line. I upgraded from Ubutnu 16.04 to 18.04 and adding `putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");` made it work again...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to use "en" for the directory name, rather than "en-US".

PHP 5.2, gettext 0.19.8.1, Ubuntu 18.04, apache2

Answer (score 0):

Two things i would consider:

- check (e.g. by using locale -a) if the language you want to use is installed a more detailed description can be found here: [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gettext.php#73376)
- check if apache is caching your file, either "disable" it or restart apache to get the new file. more info on previous link and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#58310)

Answer (score 0):

just add following line

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=en_US");
```

Comment: Why should he?  Please explain the difference (LANGUAGE instead of LANG like he did).  New users searching this subject will appreciate the extra info.